# android how to set position of button at background

Tags: android, button, position

i av an activity which extends listactivity.
i want to add a textview and a button at buttom the phone screen. so that only listview can scroll but not the button.

How to do that?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your xml layout file to something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>  
    <ListView ... />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ...>
        <TextView ... />
        <Button ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ya but if no of list items increases then it goes down n not visible at buttom of the phone screen.
I want may be listview be sroll but that textview button should be visible ta same position at buttom. please tell me how to do that?

Comment: The ListView does its own scrolling automatically